# Error "finished with non-zero exit value 1" after applying MultiDex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

We reached the 65k method limit and I was applying multidex on our app but I can't even build the app to execute now. It's not the same error and I can't find any references of this one. Some data of the app:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And by executing with the `--stacktrace` option I get this trace, but I can't identify the problem:

```
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource bolts/

no classfiles specified

:app:preDexDebug FAILED
:app:preDexDebug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.398 secs.
Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/MyUser/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/lib/dx.jar com.android.dx.command.Main --dex --verbose --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-0372c46341e44edcffa9950c76e61d5b66582e9b.jar /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.karumi/dexter/2.1.2/jars/classes.jar
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:116)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor$waitForTasksWithQuickFail$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex.taskAction(PreDex.groovy:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1296)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:122)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1248)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$preDexLibrary$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy:150)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
    ... 6 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.468 secs
PREDEX CACHE HITS:   0
PREDEX CACHE MISSES: 0
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
processing archive /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app/libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.3.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/parse/
processing com/parse/ACRA.class...

processing archive /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/cardview-v7/23.1.1/jars/classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/cardview/
processing android/support/v7/cardview/BuildConfig.class...

Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/MyUser/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/lib/dx.jar com.android.dx.command.Main --dex --verbose --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output /Users/MyUser/Development/Android/MyCoolApp/MyCoolApp-android/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/otto-1.3.8-990d2291a0d2e66eb786c410c20d4bc1acb41469.jar /Users/MyUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/otto/1.3.8/cf615176cd1177edf71d3c9605f8dc148fede6be/otto-1.3.8.jar
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea on what is happening? (I can provide more info if necessary).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by parse library, so replacing this:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

With the new library version in parts:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
```

Did the trick.